# Как отобразить navbar-brand превышающий размерами navbar?

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Судьба-злодейка вынуждает бэкендера в моём лице ковырять вёрстку. Спасался бутстрапом, но наткнулся на проблему, на помощь с которой очень надеюсь и уповаю, так как гуглил по нескольким запросам и аж до 10-й страницы, но тщетно.

Хочется мне отобразить в `navbar-brand` изображение большей высоты, чем сам `navbar`. Да так, чтобы navbar при этом не растягивался. Установка `max-height` для `navbar` решила эту хотелку в Chrome и FF

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не в IE10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первое, что пробовал - это установить отрицательный отступ, но тогда лого уезжает за пределы экрана в хроме и лиске. Потом пришло в голову обернуть `navbar` в ещё один `div`, в котором абсолютно спозиционировать изображение. Но боюсь, что это на корню зарубит адаптивность navbar'а.

Код:

```css
header .navbar {
    max-height: 56px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-success">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7aqK.png" lass="d-inline-block align-top" alt="Герб">
                Сайт
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="line.html">Раздел 1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Раздел 2
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Подраздел 1</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Подраздел 2</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Раздел 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Раздел 4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signInModal">
                            <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Войти
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как вариант использовать `hack` для `ie10+`

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  

   .navbar .container{
       margin-top: -22px;
     }

}
```